# Strange google result listing, invalid URL created

Tags: url, hash

Would be great if you guys could shed some light on this, has baffled me:

I was asked by a client if I could try and make the search term for his comedy night "sketchercise" put his website top of the Google ranking. I simply changed the title tag of the header for the whole site from "Allnutt and Simpson" to "Allnutt and Simpson - Sketchercise @ Ginglik - Sketch Duo". It did the trick and now the site comes up top of the Google listing when typing in "sketchercise". However, it gives off this very strange link:

http://www.allnuttandsimpson.com/index.php/videos/

This is the link to the google search result too:

http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=sketchercise

This link is invalid, it doesn't make any sense. I guess it has something to do with the use of hash tags and the AJAX driven site, but before I changed the title tag, it linked to the site fine using the # tags. What is the deal with this slash?

The strangest part is that the valid URL for the videos page on that site is /index.php#vidspics, I have never used the word "videos" in a url!

If anyone can explain the cause of this or just help me stop it from happening, I'd be very grateful. I realise that this is an SEO question and I hate that stuff generally, but I hope you can see this is a bit of a strange case!

Just to compare, if you google "allnutt and simpson" it works just fine links to the site and all of it's pages absolutely fine as .php pages (and then my JS converts them to hash tags to keep things clean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because there must be a folder called 'videos' under your hosted files, use an FTP client and check this.

Google crawls every folder and file unless you tell him not to do this, look for robot.txt files to learn how to avoid indexation.

Also ask google to remove that result when you solve this.

Finally that behaviour is not related with hash tags, these are just references to javascript in order to display the appropiate content in you webpage.

Comment: That's the strange thing, there is no such folder and I'm pretty sure there never has been. Also, if this were the case, why would the url be "index.php/videos"? that's not even a valid URL! However thanks for the robots.txt file advice, I'll have to look into that.

Comment: Maybe something related with mod_rewrite of apache, are you using it?

Comment: Not using any sort of mod_rewrite. I've just made a robots.txt file that looks like this: 

User-agent: *
Disallow: /index.php/videos

Hopefully that will sort it out. I'll tick this as the answer if it does (you got there first with the robots.txt advice). Still going to be a bit of a mystery.

Comment: Had to use the Google webmaster tools to remove the entry but I think the robots.txt was important to prevent from happening again.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why its posted like this but the only way to stop that page from appearing is using a google webmaster account for this website and make sure the crawlers can't find this link anymore. The alternative is have the site admin put this tag,  `<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">` , in the header when  `isset($_REQUEST(videos))` is true.
The slash in the address is the parsed form of www.allnuttandsimpson.com/index.php?=videos. You can have the web server change all the php parameters into slashes to make the links look pretty.
Best option for correct results is to create a sitemap and submit it to https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/ for that site. You will need access.

Oh forgot, the sitemap will make google see all the pages you want it to post, use this for the major pages like those in the main menu. To remove links you don't want requires a robots.txt in the main directory of the site.